# How to make decimal part rounding filter, using python pandas Dataframe apply method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I want to make decimal filter with pandas Dataframe.
Filter will ceiling and flooring their decimal part.

Like this 
threshold is 0.3 and 0.7 
0.75 -> 1 
1.99 -> 2 
9.13 -> 9 
326.2 -> 326 
34.5 -> 34.5 
68.4 -> 68.4

```
import pandas as pd

def threshold_function(df):
    print(df)
    decimal_part = df - np.floor(df)
    if (decimal_part <= 0.3):
        return np.floor(df)
    elif (0.7 <= decimal_part):
        return np.floor(df) + 1
    return df

example = pd.DataFrame([0.75,1.99,9.13,326.2,34.5])
filtered_df = example.apply(threshold_function)
```

I don't know why data frame apply method didn't work.

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with [`np.modf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html#numpy-modf) + [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
decimal, base = np.modf(example)
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(np.select(
    [decimal <= 0.3, decimal >= 0.7],
    [base, base + 1],
    default=example
), columns=example.columns, index=example.index)
```

---

`Example`:

```
example = pd.DataFrame([[0.75, 1.99, 9.13, 326.2, 34.5],
                        [0.85, 2.65, 10.19, 42.2, 61.65]])
```

```
      0     1      2      3      4
0  0.75  1.99   9.13  326.2  34.50
1  0.85  2.65  10.19   42.2  61.65
```

`filtered_df`:

```
     0     1     2      3      4
0  1.0  2.00   9.0  326.0  34.50
1  1.0  2.65  10.0   42.0  61.65
```

---

Or a revision via [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap):

```
def threshold_function(v):
    decimal_part = v - np.floor(v)
    if decimal_part <= 0.3:
        return np.floor(v)
    elif 0.7 <= decimal_part:
        return np.ceil(v)
    return v


example = pd.DataFrame([[0.75, 1.99, 9.13, 326.2, 34.5],
                        [0.85, 2.65, 10.19, 42.2, 61.65]])
filtered_df = example.applymap(threshold_function)
```

`example`

```
      0     1      2      3      4
0  0.75  1.99   9.13  326.2  34.50
1  0.85  2.65  10.19   42.2  61.65
```

`filtered_df`:

```
     0     1     2      3      4
0  1.0  2.00   9.0  326.0  34.50
1  1.0  2.65  10.0   42.0  61.65
```